# text for the 2013 course: Shamatha and the Bodhisattva Way of Life. Class 2 on Motivation and 7 Point Mind Training

Tags: mahayana, alan-wallace

Alan mentions a handout for this class from which he's teaching the Lojong. Is there any way to acquire this hand out or; is there a text that goes along with this lojong portion of the class?

Comment: You might try contacting the sponsors of the course: Santa Barbara Institute fro Consciousness Studies
P.O. Box 3573
Santa Barbara, CA 93130 info@sbinstitute.com

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but just popped up at the beginning of my feed.

I am not sure about a handout, but the book on the subject by Alan Wallace is ***The Seven-Point Mind Training: A Tibetan Method For Cultivating Mind And Heart***

The kindle or paperback is available on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

[there are texts here on lojong](https://studybuddhism.com/en/tibetan-buddhism/mind-training)
Dr. Berzin is a guru of a tibetan Mahayana lineage and offers lojong training on his website under Tibetan Mind training. There are also audio files for the mind training lectures on his Soundcloud Study Buddhism.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific link please -- a hyperlink or instructions on how or where to find the text in question on that site?